# Referenced Url works with static number but not with variable

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates, django-urls

So i'm trying to get product_id to work and every time it comes up with this error:NoReverseMatch at /playground/hello/
Reverse for 'information' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['playground/hello/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)\Z']

It works perfectly fine if i pass a constant like the number 1 or 2(can go infinitely long based on how many objects are stored in the admin panel) instead of product_id inside the index.html file but the issue with that is that if i click on any link on the first page it redirects to the same thing no matter what i click.

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Work</th>
                <th>Type of Work</th>
                <th>Hours needed</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for context2 in context%}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href={% url 'product:information' product_id %}>{{context2.work}}</a>
                        </td>
                    <td>{{context2.genre}}</td>
                    <td>{{context2.hoursWorked}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        
        </tbody>
    
    </table>
{% endblock  %}
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello'),
    path('hello/<int:product_id>', views.detail, name='information')
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404                   
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from .models import products, typeWork


def hello(request):
    context = typeWork.objects.all()
    context2 = {'context':context}
    return render(request, 'products/index.html', context2)

def detail(request, product_id):
    context = get_object_or_404(typeWork, id=product_id)
    context2 = {'context2':context}
    return render(request, 'products/detail.html', context2)
```

Comment: The variable `product_id` in your template is not set. You never specify it in the context.

Comment: @dgw which template do you mean im sorry cause im really not sure where to enter it I thought it was called in the urls.py path

Comment: @dgw so i added the product_id into the hello class and added it to the context variable in the parenthesis of typeWork.objects.all but it pulls this error: TypeError at /playground/hello/
hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'product_id'